# Finding the limit of a sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, limsup-and-liminf

$(x_n)$ is a positive sequence and
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n}{n}=0\hspace{6mm}\limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_n}{n}\in\mathbb{R}$$
and we need to find
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{x^2_1+x^2_2+\ldots+x^2_n}{n^2}$$
I have no idea how to approach this task. I was thinking that I could maybe 
$$ \frac{x^2_1+x^2_2+\ldots+x^2_n}{n^2}=\frac{\frac{x^2_1}{2}+\frac{x^2}{2}+\ldots+\frac{x^2_n}{2}}{n^2}+\frac{\frac{x^2_1}{2}+\frac{x^2}{2}+\ldots+\frac{x^2_n}{2}}{n^2}=\frac{\frac{x^2_1}{3}+\frac{x^2}{3}+\ldots+\frac{x^2_n}{3}}{n^2}+\ldots$$
But that doesn't lead anywhere. How should I approach it? What does the second limit ($\limsup\ldots\in\mathbb{R}$) mean and how should I use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is enough to see:
$$
\frac{x_1^2+\dots x_n^2}{n^2}\leq \frac{Max_{\{i=1,\dots,n\}}(x_i)}{n}\frac{x_1+\dots x_n}{n}
$$

Now
$$
\limsup_{n\to \infty}  \frac{Max_{\{i=1,\dots,n\}}(x_i)}{n} =0, \quad \limsup_{n\to \infty} \frac{x_1+\dots x_n}{n}\in \mathbb R
$$

Then
$$
\limsup_{n\to \infty} \frac{x_1^2+\dots x_n^2}{n^2}=0.
$$

as $\frac{x_1^2+\dots x_n^2}{n^2}>0$ we conclude
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{x_1^2+\dots x_n^2}{n^2}=0.
$$

Comment: How do we know that the maximum exists and $\limsup\frac{\max}{}=0$?

Comment: Well in fact is not only a limsup, but a limit. Let $\epsilon>0$ then pick $N_1$ such that $x_n/n<\epsilon$ for $n\geq N_1$. Now let $M=Max_{\{i=1,\dots, N_1\}}x_i$ and pick $N_2$ such that $M/n<\epsilon$ for $n>N_2$.

Let $N=Max(N_1,N_2)$, then for any $n>N$
$$
\frac{Max_{\{i=1,...,n\}}(x_i)}{n}<Max\left(\frac{Max_{\{i=1,...,N_1\}}(x_i)}{n},Max_{\{i=N_1,...,N_n\}}(x_i/i)\right)<\epsilon

$$